# Android studio is showing an error, 'invalid option --enable whpx'

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

android studio is showing an error, while running AVD, like below
"invalid option --enable whpx "

please suggest a better solution to remove this

Comment: your android studio version ?

Comment: 3.1 @EbrahimBashirpour

Comment: sorry Are you using AVD for first time ?

Comment: Yes, I never used it before in this system. @EbrahimBashirpour

Comment: When you say "better solution" you actually just mean "solution"?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :)
The Android emulator requires the Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX). Ensure WHPX is properly installed and usable.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/05/08/hyper-v-android-emulator-support/

I hope this suggestion helps you

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried through your answer, but its showing Xamarin cannot be installed in this environment. But i found the solution.    The solution is just to install ARM x86 emulator to run in 3.1, Hyper-V is not necessary

Comment: @RahulSurendran ARM emulators instead of Intel ones will be terribly slow, you should use emulator with the Intel system images with Intel HAXM installed, detailed steps can be found [on this page](https://www.andreszsogon.com/using-android-8-and-9-emulators-without-android-studio/).