# Emulator failed with -enable-whpx

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

When I run app in Android Studio gradle build but emulator can't run with this message

> Emulator: F:\sdk\emulator/emulator-x86.exe: invalid option --
>   '-enable-whpx'

And this

> Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: try this answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51454914/10174508
I hope this suggestion helps you

Comment: @dinesh thanks but your answer about xamarin !